# Simple Framework with Getters and Setters in Android

Tags: simple-framework

I'm new to Simple Framework, but I didn't find any advice about the use of the Getters/Setters knowing that they are not good in Android for performance point of view.

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#GettersSetters

Is there a way to not use them in Simple-Framework ?

Comment: It mentions in the article you posted: "It's reasonable to follow common object-oriented programming practices and have getters and setters in the public interface, but within a class you should always access fields directly." I can give more detail on what that means if needed...

Comment: Dylan, ok, it means we can always be compliant with O.O. but the access to the fields, we do it however directly.

Comment: However I was able to try out the framework and it seems to work however without getters/setters in the beans.

Answer (score 1):

My answer will probably be better with code samples, but pretty much. Whenever you are dealing with the field within the class, try to use the actual variable vs a method.

example. Within your class, you would use it like the following:

```
public class Foo
{    
    public Object bar; // This would be private if I was using a getter

    public void doSomeStuff()
    {
          if(bar)
          {
              //work the bar
          }
    }

    public Object getBar()
    {
         return bar;
    }
 }
```

Then externally, it would be used like this:

```
public class OtherFoo
{
  public void somethingElse()
  {
      Foo ob = new Foo();
      inner = ob.getBar();
   }

}
```

External getters are a pro/con here, as they do break the performance rule stated, but they promote much better practices (preserved encapsulation, less nasty coupling, better maintainability, etc).

This all being said though, this performance tip can be taken with a grain of salt, since Android devices have gotten more and more powerful (in fact, I'm very certain this performance hit has almost been removed as of GingerBread).

My personal recommendation is to follow OOP principle, and use getters when possible, unless there is a serious performance issue.

Comment: So you suggest to not care to access to the field directly but continuing to use O.O. way to get the value?

Comment: Outside of the method, no. Within a method, sure you can. If you feel more comfortable using a getter for all pieces, then you can. My point at the end was that those performance tips aren't really applicable anymore, since Android has gotten much better as a whole...

Comment: I agree with this reason: "My personal recommendation is to follow OOP principle, and use getters when possible, unless there is a serious performance issue."